# Zend "destructor"?

Tags: database, zend-framework, zend-db, disconnect

We use the Zend framework for MVC and Pear for accessing the database. I was wondering should I close the connection to the database everytime a request is completed? And if so is there a way to do this elegantly?

We have about 50 actions spread across multiple controllers, and I don't really want to put db->disconnect() at the end of each controller. Is there a way that I can put this disconnect command in one location, a "destructor" if you will, and have Zend call this automatically whenever a request is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment I can think of two possibilities that you could consider.

First, you could put your "destructor" in a controller [plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) in e.g. dispatchLoopShutdown hook.

Second, if you really want something to be executed at the very end of you request, you could put your "destructor" after `$application->bootstrap()->run();` in your index.php.

Comment: Use this sparingly is what I recommend. Make a choice on this based on average user time (number of request) spent on the application and number of users on your site. Make a bet based on the numbers and usage in service or controller and usage of non-persistent connections.

Answer (score 0):

Only 100% bulletproof solution is using `register_shutdown_function()`. It's called even if request is redirected (`$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrlAndExit()`) or script is killed (using `die()` or `exit()`). Both - plugin and index's last line can fail on redirect or killed script.